Optimization of cylinder rotation to overlap to 3D array
My 3D array of labels contains one label "109" roughly representing a cylinder. I can find the height, radius and center coordinates with skimage.measure. Next, I can draw another cylinder at these coordinates, with the same height and radius. To find the angles of rotation, I'd like to rotate the new cylinder along the three principal axes and optimize the three angles until both cylinders overlap within a margin.
This is what I have so far:
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from skimage import measure
import raster_geometry as rg
from scipy import optimize, ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = "./ImageJ/stack/"
padding = 1

maskList = []
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    f = os.path.join(path, filename)
    # checking if it is a file
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        if f[-3:] == "tif":
            print(f[-8:-4])
            im = np.asarray(Image.open(f))
            maskList.append(im)
            
maskStack = np.stack(maskList)

label = 109

mask = (maskStack==label)                       # set everything not equal to label to zero

regions = measure.regionprops(measure.label(mask))[0]
X, Y, Z = np.shape(mask)
x0, y0, z0 = regions.centroid
radius = regions.major_axis_length / 2.
height = regions.minor_axis_length
a0, a1, a2 = (0, 0, 0)

def cost(params):
    a0, a1, a2 = params
    cyl = rg.cylinder(np.shape(mask), height, radius, 0, (x0/X,y0/Y,z0/Z))
    rotx = ndimage.rotate(cyl, a0, mode='nearest', axes=(0,1), reshape=False, order=0)
    roty = ndimage.rotate(rotx, a1, mode='nearest', axes=(0,2), reshape=False, order=0)
    rotz = ndimage.rotate(roty, a2, mode='nearest', axes=(1,2), reshape=False, order=0)
    template = np.zeros_like(mask)
    template[rotz] = True
    return -np.sum(template == mask)

a = optimize.fmin(cost, (a0, a1, a2), xtol=0.00001, ftol=0.00001, maxiter=100, disp=True, retall=True)

The code runs, but after six iterations the convergence is apparently satisfied and the program terminates with the results (0, 0, 0) - no rotation necessary.
But, when I rotate the cylinder 1 degree over each axis, the function cost((1, 1, 1)) already returns a more negative value than cost((0, 0, 0)), which would be more optimal. So, what is going wrong here?
